# Sitecore OMS: OMS Profile scoring history for a logged in user’s profile over multiple sessions

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

We are currently exploring Sitecore personalization options for an upcoming project. I know we can attach profiles to certain pages; and use the aggregate scores for these profiles and/or their profile key score values for the session to customize content around the site. But what I want to know is this: is it possible for this profile scoring to be persisted outside of a logged in user’s given session, such as a profile scoring history feature? For example, if a logged in user always visited a given page with an attached Profile A over multiple sessions; they would build up a certain Profile A score over time; and would be flagged as a Profile A user. However, it seems to me that this profile scoring and mapping only pertains to individual user sessions, but not to actual logged in users’ profiles.

Is it possible to access these profile scores over multiple sessions for a given user; or am I restricted to just scores for the current session? I know I could probably write something custom to store this data; but I just want to see what is possible out of the box with Sitecore before I go down that road. Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OMS does persist this information over multiple sessions, so long as cookies are not cleared.

There is an OMS-specific training course, which you might find informative.  Having already taken the .NET developer course, I found it a bit tedious at times, but there was also some good gems of information to be found.

Answer (score 2):

You raise a very valid question; I've been wondering about some of the same issues myself. I haven't found all that much in way of documentation - but I'll feed you what I do know; see if anyone else can fill in the remaining blanks :-)

From looking at the Analytics Database; there is a foreign key in the Session table named "GlobalSessionId".

Looking further into the table "GlobalSession", it basically ties in a "CookieValue", a "VisitorIdentification", "OverriddenVisitorIdent" and "ExternalUser".

Now, to me, this suggests - if nothing else - that Sitecore Analytics DOES persist these values across sessions - but ties it into a cookie value, NOT the currently logged on user. Perhaps.

I guess what I'm saying is - I think this is almost box functionality, if not purely box functionality. I just don't know for absolute certain, since I've never actually tested and verified this myself - and I've found no official document stating this fact.

Point your SQL Management Studio to your Analytics database and see what's actively logged into these tables on your specific solution; perhaps this will shed even more light on matters :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sitecore.net/en/Support/Training/Course-Overview/OMS-11-NET-Developer.aspx

Master concepts and techniques for building winning marketing automation website solutions with Sitecore Online Marketing Suite (OMS) and Visual Studio 2010. The OMS .NET Developer course features live demonstrations, formal reviews, questions and answers and guided student exercises. Designed to help you achieve mastery of Sitecore OMS development practices, only Sitecore Certified Trainers deliver Sitecore OMS .NET Developer training.